# getSupportedColorEffects on samsung galaxy S7 gives empty array

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-galaxy

When running the code: `mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();` on a Samsung Galaxy S7 it returns an empty array. On other devices this returns the correct list of supported effects.

Even though the array is empty on the S7, I am able to successfully set `cameraParameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);` on my mCamera.

I assume this is a bug with this particular phone, but is there something I could have done wrong?

Comment: find same solution about that?

Comment: I simply assume that a few basic effects exists, and accept a failure if the camera does not support the effect.

Comment: There is the same problem on s6 edge on android 7... I think is a Samsung device bug.